# jquery mobile list view that posts

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile

Given a list of jquery mobile items.

```
<ul data-role=listview" data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="/dostuff?item=1">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="/dostuff?item=2">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="/dostuff?item=3">One</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a best practice way of doing the following:

make each item post to the server. I have an MVC method that accepts a post only. I would rather not use a 'Get'. I want each of the items to post to the server.

once the post is successful each item must be removed from the list.

jquery mobile does a whole lot of ajax work out of the box. What is the best way to achieve this. I don't want to write a ton of jquery to do it if there's a better way.

I can set data-role="button" on each of the li items, but would prefer the styling to stay the same. There doesn't appear to be an equivalent data-role="submit" though that would probably be perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the list item as

```
<li style="padding: 0" class="ui-btn-up-a">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false", @class = listButton" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="submit" value="Post me" />
    }
</li>
```

and add the CSS

```
.listButton .ui-btn {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.listButton .ui-btn-inner {
    padding: 0.4em 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```